# Custom Keyboard crash shared-library-event (Memory leak?)

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode, custom-keyboard

I have a custom keyboard with images divided in categories. Rigth now I have like 12 images in each category. If I have a category with 20 images, for example the keyboard crashes. I've been looking for a solution for a long time with no luck.
When I debug the keyboard in my iPhone I get a SIGQUIT signal:

```
    dyld`_dyld_start:
->  0x10014d000 <+0>:   mov    x28, sp
    0x10014d004 <+4>:   and    sp, x28, #0xfffffffffffffff0
    0x10014d008 <+8>:   mov    x0, #0x0
    0x10014d00c <+12>:  mov    x1, #0x0
    0x10014d010 <+16>:  stp    x1, x0, [sp, #-0x10]!
    0x10014d014 <+20>:  mov    x29, sp
    0x10014d018 <+24>:  sub    sp, sp, #0x10             ; =0x10 
    0x10014d01c <+28>:  ldr    x0, [x28]
    0x10014d020 <+32>:  ldr    x1, [x28, #0x8]
    0x10014d024 <+36>:  add    x2, x28, #0x10            ; =0x10 
    0x10014d028 <+40>:  adrp   x4, -1
    0x10014d02c <+44>:  add    x4, x4, #0x0              ; =0x0 
    0x10014d030 <+48>:  adrp   x3, 52
    0x10014d034 <+52>:  ldr    x3, [x3, #0xd90]
    0x10014d038 <+56>:  sub    x3, x4, x3
    0x10014d03c <+60>:  mov    x5, sp
    0x10014d040 <+64>:  bl     0x10014d088               ; dyldbootstrap::start(macho_header const*, int, char const**, long, macho_header const*, unsigned long*)
    0x10014d044 <+68>:  mov    x16, x0
    0x10014d048 <+72>:  ldr    x1, [sp]
    0x10014d04c <+76>:  cmp    x1, #0x0                  ; =0x0 
    0x10014d050 <+80>:  b.ne   0x10014d05c               ; <+92>
    0x10014d054 <+84>:  add    sp, x28, #0x8             ; =0x8 
    0x10014d058 <+88>:  br     x16
    0x10014d05c <+92>:  mov    x30, x1
    0x10014d060 <+96>:  ldr    x0, [x28, #0x8]
    0x10014d064 <+100>: add    x1, x28, #0x10            ; =0x10 
    0x10014d068 <+104>: add    x2, x1, x0, lsl #3
    0x10014d06c <+108>: add    x2, x2, #0x8              ; =0x8 
    0x10014d070 <+112>: mov    x3, x2
    0x10014d074 <+116>: ldr    x4, [x3]
    0x10014d078 <+120>: add    x3, x3, #0x8              ; =0x8 
    0x10014d07c <+124>: cmp    x4, #0x0                  ; =0x0 
    0x10014d080 <+128>: b.ne   0x10014d074               ; <+116>
    0x10014d084 <+132>: br     x16
```

If I click continue I get. Thread 1: shared-library-event:

```
dyld`_dyld_debugger_notification:
->  0x10022cdc4 <+0>: ret
```

Doing 'bt' in the console I get :

```
* thread #1, stop reason = shared-library-event
  * frame #0: 0x000000010022cdc4 dyld`_dyld_debugger_notification
    frame #1: 0x000000010022c9a4 dyld`gdb_image_notifier(dyld_image_mode, unsigned int, dyld_image_info const*) + 112
    frame #2: 0x000000010022c5f0 dyld`notifyGDB(dyld_image_states, unsigned int, dyld_image_info const*) + 60
    frame #3: 0x0000000100224b4c dyld`dyld::notifyBatchPartial(dyld_image_states, bool, char const* (*)(dyld_image_states, unsigned int, dyld_image_info const*), bool, bool) + 1040
    frame #4: 0x000000010023035c dyld`ImageLoader::link(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, bool, bool, bool, ImageLoader::RPathChain const&, char const*) + 140
    frame #5: 0x0000000100225214 dyld`dyld::link(ImageLoader*, bool, bool, ImageLoader::RPathChain const&, unsigned int) + 228
    frame #6: 0x0000000100226274 dyld`dyld::_main(macho_header const*, unsigned long, int, char const**, char const**, char const**, unsigned long*) + 2544
    frame #7: 0x0000000100221044 dyld`_dyld_start + 68
```

Any thoughts?
**UPDATE**
I created an expection breakpoint and i got the breakpoint where I load the nib file.

```
- (void)arrangeXib{

    self.keyboard = [[[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"iPhone" owner:nil options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];

    self.inputView = (UIInputView *)self.keyboard;
}
```

Exception:

```
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = signal SIGQUIT
    frame #0: 0x00000001847b3224 libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg_trap + 8
    frame #1: 0x00000001847b309c libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg + 72
    frame #2: 0x00000001846a4ee4 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_mach_send_and_wait_for_reply + 540
    frame #3: 0x00000001846a52e8 libdispatch.dylib`dispatch_mach_send_with_result_and_wait_for_reply + 56
    frame #4: 0x00000001848ccee0 libxpc.dylib`xpc_connection_send_message_with_reply_sync + 196
    frame #5: 0x0000000185754368 CoreFoundation`__78-[CFPrefsPlistSource sendRequestNewDataMessage:toConnection:retryCount:error:]_block_invoke + 24
    frame #6: 0x00000001857797a8 CoreFoundation`CFPREFERENCES_IS_WAITING_FOR_SYSTEM_CFPREFSD + 48
    frame #7: 0x00000001857542ac CoreFoundation`-[CFPrefsPlistSource sendRequestNewDataMessage:toConnection:retryCount:error:] + 264
    frame #8: 0x000000018575348c CoreFoundation`__50-[CFPrefsPlistSource alreadylocked_requestNewData]_block_invoke + 92
    frame #9: 0x0000000185819d90 CoreFoundation`-[_CFXPreferences withConnectionForRole:performBlock:] + 48
    frame #10: 0x00000001857533e4 CoreFoundation`-[CFPrefsPlistSource alreadylocked_requestNewData] + 288
    frame #11: 0x0000000185750be4 CoreFoundation`_copyValueForKey + 548
    frame #12: 0x00000001857511f0 CoreFoundation`-[CFPrefsPlistSource copyValueForKey:] + 60
    frame #13: 0x0000000185818418 CoreFoundation`__66-[_CFXPreferences copyValueForKey:identifier:user:host:container:]_block_invoke + 40
    frame #14: 0x0000000185813758 CoreFoundation`-[_CFXPreferences(SourceAdditions) withSourceForIdentifier:user:byHost:container:cloud:perform:] + 748
    frame #15: 0x000000018577af20 CoreFoundation`-[_CFXPreferences(SearchListAdditions) with23930198HackSourceForIdentifier:user:byHost:container:cloud:perform:] + 360
    frame #16: 0x0000000185818378 CoreFoundation`-[_CFXPreferences copyValueForKey:identifier:user:host:container:] + 336
    frame #17: 0x000000018754b3d0 ImageIO`IOPreferencesGetBoolean + 196
    frame #18: 0x000000018754c14c ImageIO`InitDebugFlags + 3136
    frame #19: 0x000000018468e9a0 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_client_callout + 16
    frame #20: 0x000000018468f6cc libdispatch.dylib`dispatch_once_f + 56
    frame #21: 0x0000000187462ad8 ImageIO`CGImageSourceCreateWithFile + 364
    frame #22: 0x000000018b96c178 UIKit`ImageRefAtPath + 300
    frame #23: 0x000000018b96bff0 UIKit`GetImageAtPath + 36
    frame #24: 0x000000018b96bc60 UIKit`_UIImageAtPath + 396
    frame #25: 0x000000018be10a1c UIKit`-[UIImageNibPlaceholder initWithCoder:] + 524
    frame #26: 0x000000018bf5da50 UIKit`UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 680
    frame #27: 0x000000018bf5d790 UIKit`-[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 104
    frame #28: 0x000000018bca5ec4 UIKit`-[UIImageView initWithCoder:] + 132
    frame #29: 0x000000018bf5da50 UIKit`UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 680
    frame #30: 0x000000018bf5dbc8 UIKit`UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 1056
    frame #31: 0x000000018bf5d790 UIKit`-[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 104
    frame #32: 0x000000018bbed3ec UIKit`-[UIView initWithCoder:] + 652
    frame #33: 0x000000018be0f8d8 UIKit`-[UIClassSwapper initWithCoder:] + 248
    frame #34: 0x000000018bf5da50 UIKit`UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 680
    frame #35: 0x000000018bf5d790 UIKit`-[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 104
    frame #36: 0x000000018be0f548 UIKit`-[UIRuntimeConnection initWithCoder:] + 136
    frame #37: 0x000000018bf5da50 UIKit`UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 680
    frame #38: 0x000000018bf5dbc8 UIKit`UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 1056
    frame #39: 0x000000018bf5d790 UIKit`-[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 104
    frame #40: 0x000000018be0e8bc UIKit`-[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1168
    frame #41: 0x000000018be10d40 UIKit`-[NSBundle(UINSBundleAdditions) loadNibNamed:owner:options:] + 224
  * frame #42: 0x00000001000b9698 Keyboard`-[KeyboardViewController arrangeXib](self=0x0000000121e058e0, _cmd="arrangeXib") at KeyboardViewController.m:346
    frame #43: 0x00000001000bbbc4 Keyboard`-[KeyboardViewController viewDidLoad](self=0x0000000121e058e0, _cmd="viewDidLoad") at KeyboardViewController.m:514
    frame #44: 0x000000018b907ec0 UIKit`-[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 1036
    frame #45: 0x000000018b907a9c UIKit`-[UIViewController view] + 28
    frame #46: 0x000000018c1de298 UIKit`-[_UIViewServiceViewControllerOperator __createViewController:withContextToken:fbsDisplays:appearanceSerializedRepresentations:legacyAppearance:traitCollection:initialInterfaceOrientation:hostAccessibilityServerPort:canShowTextServices:replyHandler:] + 4172
    frame #47: 0x00000001857dce80 CoreFoundation`__invoking___ + 144
    frame #48: 0x00000001856d22c4 CoreFoundation`-[NSInvocation invoke] + 292
    frame #49: 0x00000001856d6e9c CoreFoundation`-[NSInvocation invokeWithTarget:] + 60
    frame #50: 0x000000018c2e0ce4 UIKit`-[_UIViewServiceImplicitAnimationDecodingProxy forwardInvocation:] + 108
    frame #51: 0x00000001857dad54 CoreFoundation`___forwarding___ + 404
    frame #52: 0x00000001856d6d4c CoreFoundation`_CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 92
    frame #53: 0x00000001857dce80 CoreFoundation`__invoking___ + 144
    frame #54: 0x00000001856d22c4 CoreFoundation`-[NSInvocation invoke] + 292
    frame #55: 0x00000001856d6e9c CoreFoundation`-[NSInvocation invokeWithTarget:] + 60
    frame #56: 0x000000018c232048 UIKit`-[_UIQueueingProxy forwardInvocation:] + 372
    frame #57: 0x00000001857dad54 CoreFoundation`___forwarding___ + 404
    frame #58: 0x00000001856d6d4c CoreFoundation`_CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 92
    frame #59: 0x00000001857dce80 CoreFoundation`__invoking___ + 144
    frame #60: 0x00000001856d22c4 CoreFoundation`-[NSInvocation invoke] + 292
    frame #61: 0x00000001856d6e9c CoreFoundation`-[NSInvocation invokeWithTarget:] + 60
    frame #62: 0x00000001857dad54 CoreFoundation`___forwarding___ + 404
    frame #63: 0x00000001856d6d4c CoreFoundation`_CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 92
    frame #64: 0x00000001857dce80 CoreFoundation`__invoking___ + 144
    frame #65: 0x00000001856d22c4 CoreFoundation`-[NSInvocation invoke] + 292
    frame #66: 0x000000018737f884 FrontBoardServices`__FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 36
    frame #67: 0x000000018737f6f0 FrontBoardServices`-[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 176
    frame #68: 0x000000018737faa0 FrontBoardServices`-[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 56
    frame #69: 0x000000018578542c CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24
    frame #70: 0x0000000185784d9c CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 540
    frame #71: 0x00000001857829a8 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 744
    frame #72: 0x00000001856b2da4 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 424
    frame #73: 0x000000018711c074 GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 100
    frame #74: 0x000000018b96d058 UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 208
    frame #75: 0x00000001848d7cd0 libxpc.dylib`_xpc_objc_main + 788
    frame #76: 0x00000001848d9984 libxpc.dylib`xpc_main + 200
    frame #77: 0x00000001863dad90 Foundation`-[NSXPCListener resume] + 180
    frame #78: 0x000000018e15712c PlugInKit`-[PKService run] + 752
    frame #79: 0x000000018e156cf0 PlugInKit`+[PKService main] + 56
    frame #80: 0x000000018e157150 PlugInKit`+[PKService _defaultRun:arguments:] + 20
    frame #81: 0x00000001863c0ba4 Foundation`NSExtensionMain + 64
    frame #82: 0x00000001846c159c libdyld.dylib`start + 4
```

**UPDATE 2:**
I'm pretty sure it has something to do with memory issues... If I display in the cell just a colored background  it works ok. Now if I display imgages, if they are less than 10-15 there's no problem but if I have more it will crash with different errors, like the ones above or:

```
libz.1.dylib`inflate:
libsystem_kernel.dylib`_kernelrpc_mach_vm_deallocate_trap:
```

At first I had a scroll view and I thought that the problem was that it loaded all the images directly, so I tried to use a collectionView but same results. I tried loading the images 3 different ways with same results:

```
UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:
UIImage imageWithData:
UIImage imageNamed:
```

Comment: Try creating an [exception breakpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17802662/exception-breakpoint-in-xcode) and reproduce the crash; you will likely get where your code crashes.

Comment: @the4kman tried and got it where I load the nib file. I will update the question with the code

Comment: Can you tell us what the actual exception is?

Comment: @CharlesSrstka I updated with what I got using the bt command when the exception came, don't know if it's what you meant. If not, please explain how to get it because I didn't get anything else in the console

Comment: If an exception is thrown, usually a name and short description of the exception get logged to the console explaining what went wrong. If it doesn't for some reason, if you set a breakpoint on objc_exception_throw and type 'po $rdi' in the debugger, you should get it. Alternatively, you could temporarily wrap the line that's crashing in a @try/@catch block and log the exception from there.

There's probably a problem with the nib file which the exception, if we can see it, will make clear.

Comment: @CharlesSrstka Didn't get anything. with the po command it said: error: use of undeclared identifier '$rdi'
And I tried thre try/catch block and didn't write anything in the console...
I believe that the problem has something to do with memory leaks, because if I add more images then the crash happens. I am loading images directly with UIImage imageNamed: - and I read that with custom keyboards we have a 30mb limitation, what can I do?

Comment: @the4kman I updated the post again... don't know if it'll be helpful. I really have no idea what else to try

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it working now. The problem had to do with memory as I expected. For 3rd party keyboards I read apple limit the memory to 30Mb.

> Memory limits for running app extensions are significantly lower than
>   the memory limits imposed on a foreground app. On both platforms, the
>   system may aggressively terminate extensions because users want to
>   return to their main goal in the host app. Some extensions may have
>   lower memory limits than others: For example, widgets must be
>   especially efficient because users are likely to have several widgets
>   open at the same time.

I had png images around 60Kb each but it had a 24bit color bitmap which made each image around 5-6Mb in memory when I loaded them. My solution was to use jpeg images instead, I won't be able to use the transparent background but at least I'll have a working app.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `DispatchQueue` to exclude a memory leak problem like this:

```
    DispatchQueue.main.async {[self] in
        // your code here. Dont forget to use "self" before your variables.

    }
```

It helps me.

> Reason for this assumption came from this WWDC video:
>   https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/413/  which indicates
>   that with the new dyld, they'll begin crashing apps immediately if
>   load times are too long. [Source](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/72567)

Answer (score 0):

My app uses PLCrashReporter lib for collecting crash logs from users' devices. If I initialize PLCrashReporter with signal handler type *Mach* like this:

`[[PLCrashReporterConfig alloc] initWithSignalHandlerType:PLCrashReporterSignalHandlerTypeMach];`

Then when I try to debug the app, it crashes with a similar stack trace:

```
Thread 2 Crashed:
0   dyld                            0x00000001018408b8 _dyld_debugger_notification + 0
1   dyld                            0x000000010183fd6c gdb_image_notifier+ 64876 (dyld_image_mode, unsigned int, dyld_image_info const*) + 172
2   dyld                            0x000000010183fa10 notifyGDB+ 64016 (dyld_image_states, unsigned int, dyld_image_info const*) + 64
3   dyld                            0x00000001018359c0 dyld::notifyBatchPartial(dyld_image_states, bool, char const* (*)+ 22976 (dyld_image_states, unsigned int, dyld_image_info const*), bool, bool) + 1348
4   dyld                            0x0000000101841e60 ImageLoader::link+ 73312 (ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, bool, bool, bool, ImageLoader::RPathChain const&, char const*) + 176
5   dyld                            0x0000000101835f8c dyld::link+ 24460 (ImageLoader*, bool, bool, ImageLoader::RPathChain const&, unsigned int) + 328
6   dyld                            0x000000010183e1a8 dlopen_internal + 716
7   libdyld.dylib                   0x0000000197b5c3bc dlopen_internal+ 21436 (char const*, int, void*) + 176
```

When running a debugger, no matter if the app is built in Debug or Release, use handler type `PLCrashReporterSignalHandlerTypeBSD`.